# worker not recovered - Current config state offset 5 is behind group assignment 20, reading to end of config log

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using a 3 nodes kafka connect cluster to write data from a source to to kafka topic and from topic to destination. Everything works fine in distributed mode but when one of the worker is stopped and then restarted then I am getting the below message.

```
[2017-09-13 23:48:44,519] WARN Catching up to assignment's config offset. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:741)
[2017-09-13 23:48:44,519] INFO Current config state offset 5 is behind group assignment 20, reading to end of config log (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:785)
[2017-09-13 23:48:45,018] INFO Finished reading to end of log and updated config snapshot, new config log offset: 5 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:789)
[2017-09-13 23:48:45,018] INFO Current config state offset 5 does not match group assignment 20. Forcing rebalance. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:765)
[2017-09-13 23:48:45,018] INFO Rebalance started (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1187)
[2017-09-13 23:48:45,018] INFO Wasn't unable to resume work after last rebalance, can skip stopping connectors and tasks (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1219)
[2017-09-13 23:48:45,018] INFO (Re-)joining group connect-cluster (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:432)
[2017-09-13 23:48:45,023] INFO Successfully joined group connect-cluster with generation 38 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:399)
[2017-09-13 23:48:45,023] INFO Joined group and got assignment: Assignment{error=0, leader='connect-1-e51c1e8b-c95a-406b-8c56-2a0d4fc432f6', leaderUrl='http://10.10.10.10:8083/', offset=20, connectorIds=[], taskIds=[oracle_jdbc_sink_test-0]} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1166)
[2017-09-13 23:48:45,023] WARN Catching up to assignment's config offset. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:741)
[2017-09-13 23:48:45,023] INFO Current config state offset 5 is behind group assignment 20, reading to end of config log (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:785)
[2017-09-13 23:48:45,535] INFO Finished reading to end of log and updated config snapshot, new config log offset: 5 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:789)
[2017-09-13 23:48:45,535] INFO Current config state offset 5 does not match group assignment 20. Forcing rebalance. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:765)
[2017-09-13 23:48:45,535] INFO Rebalance started (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1187)
[2017-09-13 23:48:45,535] INFO Wasn't unable to resume work after last rebalance, can skip stopping connectors and tasks (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1219)
[2017-09-13 23:48:45,535] INFO (Re-)joining group connect-cluster (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:432)
[2017-09-13 23:48:45,540] INFO Successfully joined group connect-cluster with generation 38 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:399)
[2017-09-13 23:48:45,540] INFO Joined group and got assignment: Assignment{error=0, leader='connect-1-e51c1e8b-c95a-406b-8c56-2a0d4fc432f6', leaderUrl='http://10.10.10.10:8083/', offset=20, connectorIds=[], taskIds=[oracle_jdbc_sink_test-0]} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1166)
[2017-09-13 23:48:45,540] WARN Catching up to assignment's config offset. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:741)
[2017-09-13 23:48:45,540] INFO Current config state offset 5 is behind group assignment 20, reading to end of config log (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:785)
[2017-09-13 23:48:46,042] INFO Finished reading to end of log and updated config snapshot, new config log offset: 5 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:789)
[2017-09-13 23:48:46,042] INFO Current config state offset 5 does not match group assignment 20. Forcing rebalance. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:765)
[2017-09-13 23:48:46,042] INFO Rebalance started (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1187)
[2017-09-13 23:48:46,042] INFO Wasn't unable to resume work after last rebalance, can skip stopping connectors and tasks (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1219)
```

Comment: Does your config topic have multiple partitions? If so, you'll have to delete it and recreate it with one partition. This is improved on 0.11

Comment: Thanks @dawsaw I am able to resolve the issue by changing the number of partitions of configs topic to 1.

Comment: @DigvijayWaghela Feel free to answer your own questions below

Answer (score 1):

You can try resolving this issue by deleting and recreating config topics or changing the group Id.